# Generate code snippet for entire collection in postman

Tags: node.js

I want to generate code snippet in nodejs for an entire collection which contains different folders and subfolders in postman.

I am able to generate code for each request individually but I want to generate for an entire collection at once.

Comment: SO is not a FREE coding service, pls add your attempt code and steps to do and specific problem along the way. People can look at your code then help you out (if having free time)